# how to separate components in an svg file in sketch

Tags: vector, svg, sketch-app

I'm given an svg file with a logo that has both text and an illustration.. it appears as a single entity in my sketch application.. is there a way to separate it (ie i want to remove the robot from this logo).. I remember I used to be able to do stuff like this in Illustrator[image]

## update

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The icon on the left shows you it is a raster (bitmap) image, which means it is not made up of layers, but of pixels. You can't edit individual elements like in a vector image. You may be able to edit it in a raster image editor, such as Photoshop, but you will have a hard time doing major edits.

Answer (score 0):

Usually everything is nested inside a folder, like so. You can select and delete all unnecessary elements and resave.

[image: removing elements]

Comment: no folders.. see update

Comment: This is a raster image, exported as SVG. You can't do anything about it, unless you find the original vector artwork.